# MSP430 and LCD Calculator

Tags: assembly, calculator, radix, msp430

I am working on a calculator that can add, subtract, multiply and divide in any base between 2 and 16 with MSP430g2553 in assembly language. I already can do this in any base but the problem is that the results of any of the operations is in hexadecimal in the registers. I need to display the result in the base entered by the user in the LCD. To display in the LCD I need to send the ascii codes  of each digit to the LCD. For example I am adding 77(base 8) + 4(base 8) = 103 (base 8), but my result is stored as 43(hex) because 103(base 8) is 43(hex). Can I do something with that hex result in the display it in the desired base in the LCD?

Comment: You need to convert the hex value to base 8. It's really just splitting the number out 3 bits at a time instead of 4. Is there a part of that you're stuck on?

Comment: I am stuck in that part but for any base. I gave an example of base 8 operation but it can be in base 2,3,4,5,6,7,8...16. I know that in octal is just splitting the number out 3 bits but what if is base 3,4,5.6,7 or any other base between 2 and 16.

Comment: Do you know the general algorithm for base conversion? You just keep dividing and taking remainders. A 'net search will turn up lots of hits.